# Form data not able to fetch angular node mongodb

Tags: node.js, angular, mongodb, express

I have an application that adds the contact information such as first name, last name and phone number to the MongoDB. With postman, it is working perfectly. Data are being added successfully.

But with angular application, I have a form that accepts those three data(`first_name`, `last_name`, `phone`). Now when I submit it shows console message saying "`Failed to add`".

My contact.component.html

```
<form (submit)="addContact()">
    <div class="form-group">
        <label for="first_name">First Name</label>
        <input type="text" [(ngModel)]="first_name" name="first_name" class="form-control">
    </div>
    <!-- /.form-group -->
    <div class="form-group">
        <label for="first_name">Last Name</label>
        <input type="text" [(ngModel)]="last_name" name="last_name" class="form-control">
    </div>
    <!-- /.form-group -->
    <div class="form-group">
        <label for="first_name">Phone</label>
        <input type="text" [(ngModel)]="phone" id="phone" name="phone" class="form-control" required>
    </div>
    <!-- /.form-group -->
    <input type="submit" class="btn-btn-success" value="Add Contact">
</form>
```

contacts.component.ts

```
    import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
  import {ContactService} from '../contact.service';
  import {Contact} from '../contact';


  @Component({
    selector: 'app-contacts',
    templateUrl: './contacts.component.html',
    styleUrls: ['./contacts.component.css'],
    providers:[ContactService]
  })
  export class ContactsComponent implements OnInit {

  contacts: Contact[];
  contact:Contact;
  first_name:string;
  last_name:string;
  phone: string;

    constructor(private contactService: ContactService) {}

    addContact(){

        const newContact = {
            first_name: this.first_name,
            last_name : this.last_name,
            phone: this.phone
        }
        this.contactService.addContact(newContact)
        .subscribe(contact=>{
          console.log(contact); //displaymenssage
          this.contacts.push(contact);
          this.contactService.getContacts() .subscribe( contacts => this.contacts = contacts);
        });

    }

    deleteContact(id:any){
        var contacts = this.contacts;
        this.contactService.deleteContact(id)
        .subscribe(data=>{
            if(data.n==1) {
                for(var i=0; i<contacts.length; i++) {
                    if(contacts[i]._id == id) {
                        contacts.splice(i,1);
                    }
                }
            }
        })
    }
    ngOnInit() {
        this.contactService.getContacts()
        .subscribe( contacts => 
            this.contacts = contacts);
    }

  }
```

when I debug I see that addContact function is not receiving data from the ng form

getting this error 
[image]

Please help me to debug the code.
Any help will be greatly appreciated.

Comment: share your service file or post it in stackblitz

Comment: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-wvckyu?file=contact.service.ts as discuss here is the file

Comment: I can see data in the console.

Comment: @RahulSharma are you able to see that the data is going through the function addContact at contacts.component.ts ?

Comment: yes, I have added console It works {"first_name":"ABC","last_name":"XYZ","phone":"1234567980"}

Comment: are you using angular 2.?

Comment: Yes @PrasanthS I am using agular 2

Comment: @RahulSharma I have added screenshot of error I am receiving. I am still not able to get those value.

Comment: headers.append('Content-Type', 'application/json');

Comment: The spelling of application seems a mistake. Thank @PrasanthS. It seem now working on stackblitz. not working on localhost.

Comment: I'm getting data in ts file but API is not responding.

Comment: Thanks @PrasanthS . It is now working on localhost too. Please post your answer so I can accept it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Guess a typo error, and one more angular 2 has disadvantages in http interceptors.
Upgrade to latest angular.

```
headers.append('Content-Type', 'application/json');
```

Comment: You mean with latest angular it will be easy to debug such errors ?

Comment: you can attach headers for request,

Comment: angular 5 has super improved error handling, you can easily identify what the exact error is

Comment: will try Angular 5 Thanks